# What is the relationship between Time-To-Expiry and Delta?

Tags: options, greeks, delta

Is there any regular relationship between Delta and the Time-To-Expiry of an option?

I have observed that options that expiry sooner are more sensitive to underlying movements (with equal strikes). Is there any way to justify this relationship?

I suppose that at some point as well as the options get's closer to the expiry it's delta will be much lower for deep-in-the money or deep-out-of-the-money option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a page from [The Options Guide](http://www.theoptionsguide.com/delta.aspx) with an understandable picture.

[image: Time to expiration and delta]

They explain,

> As the time remaining to expiration grows shorter, the time value of the option evaporates and correspondingly, the delta of in-the-money options increases while the delta of out-of-the-money options decreases.

This happens because the shorter expiration that is deep in-the-money tends to behave as the stock, with an underlying gain of $1 having an option movement of more than 95 cents (that's a delta > 0.95).

But with a shorter expiration, the out-of-the-money option has very little chance of being exercised. Thus, the option movement is small, perhaps 5 cents (that is, a delta around 0.05).

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the Greek commonly referred to as Charm. This is a quick visualization with a good chart I found on Google:

https://www.optiontradingtips.com/greeks/charm.html

Comment: Along with Charm, have a look at Color too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the 'delta' has correlation with 'theta'. It is called 'second-order greek Charm' .  For OTM options, the delta in last few days of trading is approaching 0(zero), while for ITM options delta approaching 1(one) in last few days of trading. 
here few examples:
example_1: 
price of underlying = $100, strike = 110, interest rate = 1, implied volatility = 100 . (out of the money call option)
[image: delta tends to move closer to 0]

example_2:
price of underlying = $100, strike = 90, interest rate = 1, implied volatility = 100 . (in the money call option) 
[image: delta tends to move closer to 1]

more details could be found at this article:
https://optionstrade.info/delta-vs-time-decay/

Comment: Please make the answer stand on its own by incorporating the charts into the answer.

Comment: I think the sentence "Yes, the 'delta' has correlation with 'theta'." is problematic. First, "correlation" is a measure of linear dependence. Second, instead of "theta" which is the price sensitivity you probably mean "time-to-maturity". I think "Yes, 'delta' has a time-to-maturity dependence." makes more sense.